# why does mysql return all rows

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm using phpmyadmin to create a database and table. the table in question has these columns:

DepartureCity | ArrivalCity | TakeoffDate | TakeoffTime | LandingTime | AirlineName | Price

now whenever I use this query;

```
select * from mynewdatabase.flights where DepartureCity = 'Rome' and ArrivalCity = 'Istanbul' and TakeoffDate = '12.06.2013' and price <= '75' ORDER BY Price
```

I get all the rows instead of none. I expect none because there are no flights with a price smaller then 75 €. All the fields are Text. What is the cause of this and how can I get an empty result as I expected?

EDIT: For example when I use the same query but with price <= '400' it returns only the flights that have prices that are less than or equal to 400. The error occurs only when there are no flights that satisfy the criteria.

Comment: Where are you running the query?  I suspect this is a problem in the code around the query rather than with the query itself.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I ran the query first in the web service I wrote, then I suspected the same thing as you did and ran it from the phpmyadmin but the results are same.

Comment: . . A typical reason for this to happen is having an `or` in the `where` clause with no parens around the rest.  Your clause however has only and.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you expect it, mysql will compare the numbers, not the text.

If the column price is of any number-type, write like this:

```
and price <= 75
```

If it's text and you want to keep it as text, you need to convert it with CAST:

```
SELECT * FROM mynewdatabase.flights WHERE Price<=75 ORDER BY CAST(Price AS SIGNED);
```

this will convert the queried text value to a signed (integer), and the column type will remain text

Comment: all the fields are of text type. Is there a way to overcome this without changing the type?

Comment: @IAM . . . Could you explain how this would result in the observed behavior?  It is not obvious to me.